# It seems Xamarin ListView binding is broken in updated VS 2019 16.11.3. CollectionView binding too. Can Someone look into it?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms, binding

I  wasted 2 days to figure out whats the issue but I couldnt. I tried all the possible examples, source codes from Github, tutorials, articles etc. I could not bind the List and its contents to a ListView or CollectionView.

Visual studio Version 16.11.3
Xamarin Version
[image]

My ViewModel. I tried using list and observable collection.
[image]

My CodebehindFile. I tried Binding from Xaml as well as from code behind file.
[image]

my Xaml file. I spent 2 days figuring out this Binding issue :(
[image]

A simple class in the model.
[image]

I wrote a new page which works with basic declaration of ListView contents but...,
[image]

I have copied the working code on to the Main page but its not working on the MainPage. The listView which works fine on the other page doesnt work on the main page.
[image]

If I comment out the Item template, somehow I see the list of strings bound to the UI.
[image]

if I uncomment, I see that Item template works but
[image]

If I restart the app, I need to repeat the process.
Everything with ListView Binding and collectionView Binding is screwed. We have declare the contents of lists and collections as public properties and access from ViewModel. Its hectic

Comment: do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: If you upload your repo somewhere it would be easier to diagnose what your actual issue is.

Comment: I checked the code in the repo you provided. It works well. Please check my screenshot. https://imgur.com/undefined Could you provide more details for me to reproduce?

Comment: Here is a repo zang. https://github.com/fewbackseven/listView/. Anyway James sorted it out. I had to specify the datatype of my class separately to a data template. I had a hunch but i didnt know how to do it. I checked tutorials, articles and offficial Microsoft docs but I couldnt find the solution. Finally I had to post it here. Anyway Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you had set `x:DataType` for the page, which is awesome because it is compiled bindings, however it means you also need to set it on and DataTemplate so it knows the type of the item inside of it. So for the first `ListView` that is a string you would do `<DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">` and then for your customer it would be `<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Customer">`

Take a look at this repo, seems to work for me based on what I see: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/App4 & https://github.com/fewbackseven/listView/pull/1

Comment: I have uploaded my broken project in a repo. In this project the issue still persists. Please have a look at it once. I was learning PRISM and I just drag and dropped this LISTVIEW from their TOOLBOX.
https://github.com/fewbackseven/listView

Comment: Wow.. You guys are amazing.. Thanks for your support. I am sorry. I somehow  failed to find this in articles or tutorials or official Microsoft docs :( . I was referencing and learning from your "MONKEY FINDER" tutorial but now I cant find it too :(